# Does the Pokemon that spawns on Honey Tree stay there forever?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

I'm playing Shining Pearl and I can put honey on the yellow trees. Does the pokemon that spawns stay there forever for me to go capture it, or does it leave after some time passes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Honey_Tree):

> If a tree is left unchecked for 24 hours, both the Honey and any Pokémon will be gone.

Comment: That sucks, I guess I can't just put it on every tree I see.

Comment: @temp there's a chance for a Pokemon to spawn after 6 hours, you just have to rinse and repeat.

Comment: @temp don't worry. You can buy honey for 100 pokebucks from guy that gave you first one at Floaroma Meadow.

Comment: Also wild Combee used to held Honey with 100% chance in old DP